# Python type-aware docstring standard

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, docstring, python-typing

It seems to me that popular python docstring formats (sphinx, google, numpy) and the docuemtnation-generation tools that support them, aren't type aware.

In that I'd have to write something like:

```
def a(b: Option[C] = default_val) -> D:
    """
    b: C, optional
        default: default_val
        A description of the argument b
    
    Returns an object of type D
    """
```

Instead of:

```
def a(b: Option[C] = default_val) -> D:
    """
    b: A description of the argument b
    """
```

Are there any docstring formats that are officially supported by at least one documentation generation tool that are type and default value aware?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/agronholm/sphinx-autodoc-typehints

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I needed :)